# Почему на букву Ё всегда падает ударение?

Tags: русская-графика

Детский вопрос. Так может спросить только излишне любопытный малолетний школьник. **Но как на этот вопрос ответить?**

Наверное, надо сказать так:

— Потому что на звук О после мягких согласных всегда падает ударение. — Значит, буква Ё  обозначает не только звук, но и ударение? Поэтому нельзя писать Ё, если слог станет безударным?

— Да нет, конечно. Давай рассмотрим пару слов ***тёмный — темнеть***.  В первом слове какой ударный звук? — Звук О.

— А во втором слове? — Во втором слове безударный звук И.

— Вот безударный звук И мы и обозначаем буквой Е, а не буквой Ё. — А почему не буквой Ё?  Разве буква Ё не может обозначать безударный звук И?

**Есть ли какие-нибудь ошибки** в этом детском рассуждении?

Comment: В редких случаях мы становимся свидетелями того, что у заимствованных слов буква Ё находится без ударения, например,кёнигсбе́ргские сёрфинги́сты. Это явление наблюдается и в словах с приставками трёх- и четырёх-:четырёхча́стный

Answer (score 1):

Мне видится логичным аргумент со звуком "о", поскольку "окание" противоречит современным нормам произношения. Есть лишь исключения иноязычного происхождения, когда при записи через "ё" безударный "о" выговаривается: Расёмон.

Comment: Это да, но ведь звук - это не буква. Мы связали Ё с ударным О, но что мешает нам писать ее в безударном слоге, в котором гласный все равно редуцируется в И. Ведь Е без ударения мы тоже редко произносим, но тем не менее пишем  вместо Ё.  Значит, буква Ё - это  только привычка, дополнительный признак ударного слога?

Comment: Видимо, ещё и память о том, что  когда-то произошло изменение е в о (передвижка гласного по ряду и его огубление, т.е. лабиализация) именно под ударением в позиции после мягкого согласного перед следующим твёрдым согласным:

Answer (score 0):

А вот похожий вопрос  -  задание из олимпиады за 5 класс.

> Переход "е" в "о" под ударением происходил по нескольким правилам
>   t~et>t~ot, где t -- согласный звук. "Переведите" это правило, объяснив
>   его словами. Объясните, почему в слове "пёрышко" мы произносим О, а в
>   словах перо и перья -- нет.  Знак ~ обозначает мягкость.

Школьник просит помощи на сайте, а что-то ему никто не ответил. Может, потому что это олимпиада (не поважать лентяя), может, потому  что решили: это легко, а может, не захотели напрягаться.

А ведь здесь только и надо, что формулу прочитать : е  переходил в о под ударением в позиции после мягкого согласного перед следующим твёрдым согласным.

Вот и весь ответ. Буква Ё могла быть только на месте буквы Е. На неё всегда падает ударение, потому что она обозначает звук О, который и появился под ударением после мягкого согласного перед твёрдым: пёрышко. В слове перо нет ё, потому что на первый слог не падает ударение, а в слове перья после е следует мягкий согласный.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо большое за ответ, было интересно читать. Но заданный вопрос был рассчитан не на знание истории, а на современное состояние языка. Если обращаться в прошлое, то фонетический и буквенный состав значительно изменился. Меня в вопросе интересовало такое состояние: допустим, что мы про историю ничего не знаем. Просто хотим понять современную логику. Можно ли сейчас  безоговорочно принять это утверждение про всегда ударную букву Ё. Насколько оно логично именно сейчас, может ли что-либо измениться в будущем?

Comment: Фонетический строй современного русского литературного  языка таков, что чистый гласный звук О мы слышим только в сильной позиции, т.е. под ударением, в остальных позициях мы слышим редуцированные звуки - ослабленный А,Ъ,Ь. Теперь это знают даже в начальных классах, там теперь тоже фонетический анализ, транскрипция, и дети вряд ли зададут вопрос про Ё без ударения. Чаще они задают вопрос, почему в книжках вместо Ё пишут Е, как им объяснить, что это необязательная буква, а читать мы всё равно должны с Ё?

Comment: Мой вопрос был не о детях - история было рассказана для того, чтобы ориентироваться на непредвзятость детского мышления. Все пользователи языка еще в раннем школьном возрасте выучили правило: на букву Ё всегда падает ударение, поэтому они считают это аксиомой, не требующей доказательства. Да, история буквы такова, да только история может меняться. Я говорю не о фонетическом строе, а о букве, обозначающей звук в безударной позиции.

Comment: Без ударения мы Е тоже фактически не произносим, но тем не менее пишем букву Е. Да и О после твердых согласных мы тоже редко слышим, у О/Ё в безударной позиции примерно равное положение. Есть ли у буквы Ё другое будущее - вот о чем был вопрос. А что если консерватизм мышления мешает ей стать полноценным знаком? Формально же я спрашивала о правильности приведенного рассуждения.

Comment: Еще немного о правильных детях, задающих правильные вопросы. Скорее всего, это будущие исполнители и потребители (как вещей, так и знаний). "Правильный мир" не может развиваться. Если в нем все решено, нет загадок, тайн и противоречий, то он обречен на застой и даже деградацию. Правильные вопросы о букве Ё - это поверхностные вопросы, они не о сути предмета, они о его внешней стороне. Писать или не писать. обязательно или необязательно - вот границы такого мышления.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в "рассуждениях" сознательно перепутаны причина и следствие.
Ё пишется там и только там, где она нужна, а все разговоры про "не может обозначать" вторичны. Ё обозначает звук О под ударением после мягких согласных. Её, эту букву с такой целью и выдумали. Без ударения такого звука в такой позиции не бывает. После этого вопросы об том, почему падает ударение становится бессмысленными - на уровне "Почему крокодилы не летают".